Keyboard after connecting still not working
I connected my keyboard in linux mint:

but strangely i can't still type with the keyboard.
Can someone help me?

It's working now. I had to connect it manually over the terminal like: bluetoothctl scan on after i paired it with the id: pair ID after i got the passkey and it worked. But i'm curious if it will work after a reboot.

bluetoothctl scan on after I paired it with the id: pair ID after I got the passkey and it worked. Also working after rebooting the system.
